# Putting two 1D arrays into one 2D array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Hey guys i have two 1D arrays one with names and one with phonenumbers:

```
private string[] names = { "xaw",       "Tommy",     "Alan",   "Sergio",    "Adam",     "Pablo" };
private string[] phones = { "535-4213", "535-0421", "722-352", "070-3531", "343-2324", "344-2223" };
```

I want to put them into one 2D array.
also do i have to declare array size like this:

```
string[,] phonesNames = new string[6,2]
```

or can i leave it like this:
(without declaration of size? Will it work in this case?)

```
string[,] phonesNames;
```

The result should be pairs so phoneNames[0,0] is xaw and phoneNames[0,1] is 535-4213  like this:

```
Xaw 535-4213
Tommy 535-0421
Alan 722-352
Sergio 070-3531
Adam 343-2324
Pablo 344-2223
```

I would greatly appreciate if you helped me please.

@edit This is actually not the solution because it only appears as sorted with Console.Writeline() the array is now [2,6] but the thing i was searching for was sorted array [6,2]

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "xaw", "Tommy", "Alan", "Sergio", "Adam", "Pablo" };

        string[] phones = { "535-4213", "535-0421", "722-352", "070-3531", "343-2324", "344-2223" };


        string[,] phonesNames = new string[2, names.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            phonesNames[0, i] = names[i];
            phonesNames[1, i] = phones[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", phonesNames[0,i], phonesNames[1,i]);
    }
}
```

The solution is in just 2 lines of code in for loop

```
for (int dimension = 0; dimension < 6; dimension++)
            {
                phonesNames[dimension, 0] = names[dimension]; 
                phonesNames[dimension, 1] = phones[dimension];
            }
```

Comment: Why `5`? It should be `6`. 6 x 2 or 2 x 6.

Comment: yes my mistake 6,2

Comment: You don't need the inner loop. Just assign the elements directly (`[dimension, 0] = names[...]; [dimension, 1] = phones[...];`).

Comment: Would it not be better to combine the strings into a 1D array of something like `record Contact(string name, string telnum)`?

Comment: @NicoSchertler
 Wow actually after whole day of programming that was the solution. Because whole 2D array needs to be sorted and not just displayed as sorted with Console.WriteLine. You wrote it but I didn't get what you mean, so i spent like whole day finding the solution. The solution is just 2 lines of code in for loop. Oh man...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image][image]

```
string[] names = { "xaw", "Tommy", "Alan", "Sergio", "Adam", "Pablo" };

string[] phones = { "535-4213", "535-0421", "722-352", "070-3531", "343-2324", "344-2223" };

string[][] phoneNames = new string[2][];

phoneNames[0] = names;

phoneNames[1] = phones;

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", phoneNames[0][i], phoneNames[1][i]);


  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Do we have to use jagged array to do this?

Comment: Also is this possbile without declaring size of array? - string[,] phonesNames = new string[2, names.Length];

Comment: Yes, it is possible you can do that also ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the two 1D arrays into one 2D array, this is what I will do:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly string[] names = { "xaw", "Tommy", "Alan", "Sergio", "Adam", "Pablo" };
    private static readonly string[] phones = { "535-4213", "535-0421", "722-352", "070-3531", "343-2324", "344-2223" };
    
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] phonesNames = new string[2, names.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            phonesNames[0, i] = names[i];
            phonesNames[1, i] = phones[i];
        }

        // loop through all columns
        for (int i = 0; i < phonesNames.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            var phoneName = GetColumn(phonesNames, i);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", phoneName));
        }
    }
    
    static string[] GetColumn(string[,] matrix, int columnNumber)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0))
            .Select(x => matrix[x, columnNumber])
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
xaw 535-4213
Tommy 535-0421
Alan 722-352
Sergio 070-3531
Adam 343-2324
Pablo 344-2223
```

Visualize PhoneNames 2D Array:

[image]

To access a specific cell, you simply use:

```
Console.WriteLine(phonesNames[0,2]); // Alan
```

To access a whole column, e.g. 4th column:

```
var column4 = GetColumn(phonesNames, 4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", column4));
// output = Adam 343-2324
```

Comment: The output is diffrent the name should be combined with phone number 
the result here is 
xaw   Tommy   Alan   Sergio   Adam   Pablo
535-4213   535-0421   722-352   070-3531   343-2324   344-2223

Comment: Do you intend to print all phonenames or you want to get a specific pair?

Comment: These should be pairs so phoneNames[0,0] is xaw and phoneNames[0,1] is 535-4213

Comment: @Junus I have updated the code. Let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Damn thank you so much, but this code is very complicated for a beginner. Anyway I will try to study this code and try to understand it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @Junus I added the photo to visualize the `phoneNames` 2D array. I also removed excess code. What part is complicated, I might explain?

Comment: I dont get this getColumn function return Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(0))
            .Select(x => matrix[x, columnNumber])
            .ToArray();

Comment: @Junus This is a function to return a specific column for 2D array. Yes it is a bit complicated for now but you can use it for other future 2D arrays as well.

Comment: @Junus `phonesNames.GetLength(0)` gets the total number of rows and `phonesNames.GetLength(1)` get the total number of columns

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use ZIP Method 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0)\

```
    string[] names = { "xaw", "Tommy", "Alan", "Sergio", "Adam", "Pablo" };
    string[] phones = { "535-4213", "535-0421", "722-352", "070-3531", "343-2324", "344-2223" };
    var zipped = names.Zip(phones, (one, two) => one + " " + two);

    foreach(string name in zipped)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

Output

```
xaw 535-4213
Tommy 535-0421
Alan 722-352
Sergio 070-3531
Adam 343-2324
Pablo 344-2223
```

Comment: Thank you thats interesting soulution, but in the assignment i need to do for loop and 2d Array. Could you help me with that?